# ConnectionOptions not found c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to connect a remote computer and found a example in below link.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions.locale(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions.locale%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

However if i write

```
  ConnectionOptions options = 
            new ConnectionOptions();
```

ConnectionOption dll can not be found.There is no anything like "ConnectionOption".

What dll do i need to add in order to see ConnectionOptions ?

**My Code:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ConnectionOptions options =
      new ConnectionOptions();

    }
```

Where i miss exactly ?

Comment: Are you using `System.Management`?

Comment: Than you either misstyped or your installation is corrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConnectionOptions` is in the System.Management namespace so you'll need to add a reference in your project to [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[How to add a reference? Look here :)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: Good, then next thing to do is mark this answer as the answer :) Like that your question is marked answered on Stackoverflow ;)